# Shiny: Uploading local files to server from client

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I use fileInput to upload one file which contains the paths and file names of multiple files on my local computer.

I would then like to use these file paths and upload them to the server directly without the user having to perform any more interaction.

So simply put how do I upload a file to the shiny server I already know its local path?